# Correct threads usage in Scheme (Bigloo)

Tags: multithreading, scheme, bigloo

I'm  trying to write an application server in Scheme with Bigloo implementation. The code:

```
(module server
    (library fthread)
    (main main))

(define *port-num* 8080)

(define (main argv)
    (let* ((socket0 (make-server-socket *port-num*))
           (ts (thread-start! (make-thread (lambda () (start-server socket0))))))
         (scheduler-start!)
         (fprint (current-error-port) "Shutting down...")))

(define (start-server socket0)
        (lambda ()
        (print "Starting server...")
             (let loop ()
            (let ((s (socket-accept socket0)))
                 (print "New connection: " s)
                 (thread-start! (make-thread (lambda () (handle-request s))))
                 (thread-yield!)
                 (loop)))))

(define (handle-request s)
        (print "new request")
    (socket-shutdown s #f))
```

It compiles OK, but program terminates immediately after starting:

```
$ bigloo -o server server.scm
$ ./server 
Shutting down...
```

Where I'm wrong?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know Bigloo's fthread library, but might it be that you immediately return lambda from `start-server` instead of doing work?

Like I said, I don't know fthread, so maybe this is how you're supposed to use it. Except that in `handle-request` you don't have this lambda wrapper, and you call `make-thread` exactly the same way:

```
(make-thread (lambda () (start-server socket0)))
; vs
(make-thread (lambda () (handle-request s)))
```

If this is the problem, you can fix it either by getting rid of the lambda inside `start-server`, or by changing your first `make-thread` call to

```
(make-thread (start-server socket0))
```